# Google Calendars keeps adding calendars for colleagues to my iPhone Calendar

Tags: iphone, google-calendar

At work we use Gmail and Google Calendar. Besides my own calendar I've subscribed to some other calendars of colleagues in the past, and we use some shared calendars. At the moment I've removed all colleague calendars. In Google Calendar I don't see these calendars anymore.

iOS Calendar (or Google Calendar) keeps adding calendars continuously and it's very annoying. When I press on "Calendar" (bottom middle) I get a list of all calendars. I uncheck all that I don't want to see. When someone adds an event, it pops up and his or her calendar is suddenly added. I keep unchecking these things.

**Questions**

- Why do these calendars show up in iOS when I've removed them in Google Calendar?
- How can I permanently disable a calendar that is in the list, so it won't show up and won't show notifications?

Using iOS 16.